# Clean up database records

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, normalization

I have a database that has no real normalization, so I am going back and trying to make it a little better. Right now we have the following columns:

```
FirstName | LastName | SchoolYear | Grade | SchoolId | Games Played
 Bob      | Smith    | 2010       |  Fr   | 245      | 3
 Tina     | Johnson  | 2010       |  So   | 2894     | 10
 Bob      | Smith    | 2010       |  Fr   | 245      | 3
```

How would I find schools that have 2 people with the same name, school year, grade, and school ID? They would look like duplicates in the database (all the columns would be the same), but each player only has one row with games played for each year. This is how I know there are similar people at a school, there would be 2 rows with the same information.

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Thanks!

Comment: normalization is about not duplicating columns in a database, not the data in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this query:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, SchoolYear, Grade, SchoolId
FROM <your table>
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, SchoolYear, Grade, SchoolId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will basically find all the (FirstName, LastName, SchoolYear, Grade, SchoolId) sets that exist in more than one record.

If you are only interested in the SchoolId's of the above records, then go with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SchoolId
FROM <your table>
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, SchoolYear, Grade, SchoolId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select FirstName, LastName, SchoolYear, Grade, SchoolId
from Student
group by FirstName, LastName, SchoolYear, Grade, SchoolId
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` should do:

```
SELECT SchoolId
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, SchoolYear, Grade, SchoolId, [Games Played]
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Note that you may want to use `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` if you want to find all schools with duplicate students.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       SchoolYear,
       Grade,
       SchoolId,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS 'Repeat?'
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, SchoolYear, Grade, SchoolId
```

Comment: Thanks for the Case example, I was struggling with that

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*), FirstName, LastName, SchoolYear, Grade, SchoolId
from mytable
group by FirstName, LastName, SchoolYear, Grade, SchoolId
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: there is also a HAVING clause - note you may have some entries with more than 2 for instance...